# What ingredients are used in peri peri Powder?

Tags: ingredient-selection

I have been looking for possible ingredients that are being used to make peri peri powder.

Is there any significant difference between peri peri powder and peri peri sauce. Interms of ingredients?

Answer (score 3):

Both are similar, and there are varied recipes for peri-peri powder, as well as sauce. What they have in common are peppers (one or more varieties) and the seasonings and spices. The sauce, of course, contains liquids. Although not meant to be comprehensive, here are many of the ingredients you'll see in basic recipes for both.

**Peppers**: peri peri, red chiles (cayenne), birdseye chiles, thai chiles, serrano, sweet red pepper

**Seasonings & Spices**: salt, sugar, garlic, onion, black pepper, lemon peel, cinnamon, cardamon, ginger, paprika, chili flakes, oregano

**Liquids**: water, vinegar, oil, lemon juice, lime juice